# Share script between .gitlab-ci.yml jobs

Tags: gitlab-ci

Have a look at the snippet below. I want to find a way to reduce duplicate code by placing command_A and command_B at a location where job1 and job2 both run it

```
job1:
  script:
    - command_A
    - command_B
    - command_C

job2:
  script: 
    - command_A
    - command_B
    - command_D
```

Answer (score 6):

In your case, probably the easiest would be to use YML Anchors.

Anchors are YML's way of reusing code - you can think of them a little bit like functions.

You can define a block of configuration somewhere and create a reference to it using `&`. Then, you can use it with `*`.

```yaml
# Create an anchor called `&common`
.common: &common
  - command_A
  - command_B

job1:
  script:
   # Merge the anchor into the `script` using `<<*:`
    - *common
    - command_C

job2:
  script: 
    - *common
    - command_D
```

To learn more, I found [this article](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/) to be helpful, and of course, the [official Gitlab docs on anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors).

Alternatively, you could simply put all common code in a `before_script` tag or use `.extends` keyword - you can see [some examples](https://jsramblings.com/three-ways-to-reuse-commands-across-gitlab-jobs/) on my blog.

Comment: To merge scripts, syntax should be `- *common` without `<<:`. Otherwise `command_C` and `command_D` wont run. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_specific_features.html#yaml-anchors-for-scripts

Answer (score 4):

The above answer by Corina is logically correct but technically wrong. I have put the correct script here. Please refer [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#yaml-anchors-for-scripts) link.

```
# Create an anchor called `&common`
.common: &common
  - command_A
  - command_B

job1:
  script:
   # Merge the anchor into the `script` using `<<*:`
    - *common
    - command_C

job2:
  script: 
    - *common
    - command_D
```

Answer (score 3):

While YML Anchors works, the recommended way now is to use [Extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#use-extends-to-reuse-configuration-sections)

> You can reduce complexity and duplicated configuration in your GitLab CI/CD configuration files by using:
>
> YAML-specific features like anchors (&), aliases (*), and map merging(<<).
>
> The extends keyword,
> which is more flexible and readable. We recommend you use extends
> where possible.

Your pipeline will be :

```
.common:
  before_script:
    - command_A
    - command_B

job1:
  extends:
    - .common
  script:
    - command_C

job2:
  extends:
    - .common
  script:
    - command_D
```